# How to word wrap text stored in JTextPanes which are cells in a JList

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextarea, jtextpane

I created a `JList` that had `JTextAreas` which word wrapped appropriately when `setLineWrap(true); setWrapStyleWord(true);` was used. These aren't available for `JTextPane` and my god forsaken text isn't wrapping. Any advise?

Comment: Text panes wrap text automatically. I'm not sure what the difference is. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the working code for the text area and the changed code for the text pane so we can see what the difference is.

Comment: `JTextArea`s aren't supposed to go inside of a `JList`, so I suspect they're not behaving correctly. You should use a layout manager that can lay out the components in a vertical list - see BoxLayout http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe this example to implement your own wrap in JTextPane
http://java-sl.com/wrap.html